# Force-recall getPreferredSize() in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel

Before I start, I am aware that I may be asking the wrong question, and perhaps what I'm trying to do is a very bad idea. If this is the case, please let me know.

I have a class that overrides the `JPanel` method `getPreferredSize()` and returns a custom `Dimension` object with a specific width and height. However, when I put a debug `println()` statement in the method, I noticed it was only called once upon creation, and never called after that. I need to resize the `JPanel` as its content changes (and no, a `JScrollPane` is definitely not what I'm looking for), but I do not know how to force-recall the `getPreferredSize()` method.

If someone could explain to me how I can recall that method, it'd be greatly appreciated. Thank you all in advance!

Here is a MCVE of my code:

```
package rotation;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.swing.*;
import java.swing.event.*;

public class Rotation {

private double theta;

public Rotation() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds(new Rectangle(650, 650));
    frame.setResizable(false);

    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(400, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) image.createGraphics();
    g2.setColor(Color.red);
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    g2.dispose();

    JPanel panel = new JPanel() {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            BufferedImage img = rotate(image, theta);
            return new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            int middleX = getWidth() / 2;
            int middleY = getHeight() / 2;

            BufferedImage img = rotate(image, theta);

            g.drawImage(img, middleX - img.getWidth() / 2, middleY - img.getHeight() / 2, null);
        }
    };
    contentPane.add(panel);
    panel.setLocation(0, 0);
    panel.setSize(panel.getPreferredSize());

    JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 360, 0);
    slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            theta = slider.getValue();
            panel.revalidate();
            panel.repaint();
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(slider);
    slider.setLocation(0, 600);
    slider.setSize(slider.getPreferredSize());

    contentPane.revalidate();
    contentPane.repaint();

    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public BufferedImage rotate(BufferedImage image, double angle) {
    angle = Math.toRadians(angle);
    double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle)), cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle));
    int w = image.getWidth(), h = image.getHeight();
    int neww = (int)Math.floor(w * cos + h * sin), newh = (int) Math.floor(h * cos + w * sin);
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = getDefaultConfiguration();
    BufferedImage result = gc.createCompatibleImage(neww, newh, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
    Graphics2D g2 = result.createGraphics();
    g2.translate((neww - w) / 2, (newh - h) / 2);
    g2.rotate(angle, w / 2, h / 2);
    g2.drawRenderedImage(image, null);
    g2.dispose();
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) result.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, neww - 1, newh - 1);
    return result;
}

public GraphicsConfiguration getDefaultConfiguration() {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    return gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Rotation();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `revalidate();` and `repaint();` (both of them in that order) after you add elements to the `JPanel`? Why a `JScrollPane` wouldn't work for you?

Comment: @Frakcool I actually do not need to add items to the `JPanel`, but the size of it needs to change, as the image painted to it in `paintComponent()` changes size. To answer your question though. Yes, I do call both `revalidate()` and `repaint()`, in that order (for both that `JPanel` and it's "enclosing" `JPanel`, but the `getPreferredSize()` method is never called.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you're trying to do as it's not completely clear to me yet

Comment: `but the size of it needs to change, as the image painted to it in paintComponent() changes size.` - why create a custom component? Just use a JLabel with an Icon.

Comment: That was how I did it a while ago. However, I had to make the switch to using a `JPanel` instead of a `JLabel`, and I am unable to simply use a `JLabel` for what I need. I will create a MC&V example and edit my post.

Comment: Why you had to? I think the MCVE will tell us a lot more

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) type question. Please give more background information about the problem itself, not how you're trying to solve it, and yes, create and post that [mcve].

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels @Frakcool I added the MCVE to my post. As for my main goal, I want to use keyboard control (WASD) to move a component on a screen. When I press a key combination, such as W and D or A and S, I want the component to rotate so it is facing the proper direction. That is the X. My Y was to create a `JPanel` and draw a rotated `BufferedImage` onto it. However, my `JPanel` doesn't resize to accomodate for the fact that my `BufferedImage` is larger diagonal that it is when it's flat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we've discussed before (when you had a different user ID), it's much easier in this situation to not use a JPanel or JLabel to hold the sprite, but rather a to use a single drawing JPanel, and then draw the sprite, of whatever side needed within this single drawing JPanel.  Here is an example that uses this sprite sheet:

[image]

obtained from [this site](http://orig12.deviantart.net/7db3/f/2010/338/3/3/animated_sprite_sheet_32x32_by_digibody-d3479l2.gif).

Again it's an example of drawing within a JPanel's paintComponent method and using Key Bindings to tell which direction to move.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Mcve3 extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 800;
    private static final int PREF_H = 640;
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 50;

    private int spriteX = 400;
    private int spriteY = 320;
    private SpriteDirection spriteDirection = SpriteDirection.RIGHT;
    private MySprite sprite = null;
    private Timer timer = null;

    public Mcve3() {
        try {
            sprite = new MySprite(spriteDirection, spriteX, spriteY);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        setKeyBindings(SpriteDirection.LEFT, KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
        setKeyBindings(SpriteDirection.RIGHT, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
        setKeyBindings(SpriteDirection.FORWARD, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
        setKeyBindings(SpriteDirection.AWAY, KeyEvent.VK_UP);

        timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener());
        timer.start();
    }

    private void setKeyBindings(SpriteDirection dir, int keyCode) {
        int condition = WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
        InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
        ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

        KeyStroke keyPressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, false);
        KeyStroke keyReleased = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, true);

        inputMap.put(keyPressed, keyPressed.toString());
        inputMap.put(keyReleased, keyReleased.toString());

        actionMap.put(keyPressed.toString(), new MoveAction(dir, false));
        actionMap.put(keyReleased.toString(), new MoveAction(dir, true));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        sprite.draw(g);
    }

    private class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {
        private SpriteDirection dir;
        private boolean released;

        public MoveAction(SpriteDirection dir, boolean released) {
            this.dir = dir;
            this.released = released;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (released) {
                sprite.setMoving(false);
            } else {
                sprite.setMoving(true);
                sprite.setDirection(dir);
            }
        }
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (sprite.isMoving()) {
                    sprite.tick();
                }
                repaint();
            }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Mcve3 mainPanel = new Mcve3();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MCVE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
class MySprite {
    private static final String SPRITE_SHEET_PATH = "http://"
            + "orig12.deviantart.net/7db3/f/2010/338/3/3/"
            + "animated_sprite_sheet_32x32_by_digibody-d3479l2.gif";
    private static final int MAX_MOVING_INDEX = 4;
    private static final int DELTA = 4;
    private SpriteDirection direction;
    private Map<SpriteDirection, Image> standingImgMap = new EnumMap<>(SpriteDirection.class);
    private Map<SpriteDirection, List<Image>> movingImgMap = new EnumMap<>(SpriteDirection.class);
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private boolean moving = false;
    private int movingIndex = 0;

    public MySprite(SpriteDirection direction, int x, int y) throws IOException {
        this.direction = direction;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        createSprites();
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        Image img = null;
        if (!moving) {
            img = standingImgMap.get(direction);
        } else {
            img = movingImgMap.get(direction).get(movingIndex);
        }
        g.drawImage(img, x, y, null);
    }

    private void createSprites() throws IOException {
        URL spriteSheetUrl = new URL(SPRITE_SHEET_PATH);
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(spriteSheetUrl);

        // get sub-images (sprites) from the sprite sheet
        // magic numbers for getting sprites from sheet, all obtained by trial and error
        int x0 = 0;
        int y0 = 64;
        int rW = 32;
        int rH = 32;
        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
            SpriteDirection dir = SpriteDirection.values()[row];
            List<Image> imgList = new ArrayList<>();
            movingImgMap.put(dir, imgList);
            int rY = y0 + row * rH;
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
                int rX = x0 + col * rW;
                BufferedImage subImg = img.getSubimage(rX, rY, rW, rH);
                if (col == 0) {
                    // first image is standing
                    standingImgMap.put(dir, subImg);
                } else {
                    // all others are moving
                    imgList.add(subImg);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public SpriteDirection getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    public void setDirection(SpriteDirection direction) {
        if (this.direction != direction) {
            setMoving(false);
        }
        this.direction = direction;

    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean isMoving() {
        return moving;
    }

    public void setMoving(boolean moving) {
        this.moving = moving;
        if (!moving) {
            movingIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    public void tick() {
        if (moving) {
            switch (direction) {
            case RIGHT:
                x += DELTA;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                x -= DELTA;
                break;
            case FORWARD:
                y += DELTA;
                break;
            case AWAY:
                y -= DELTA;
            }
            movingIndex++;
            movingIndex %= MAX_MOVING_INDEX;
        }
    }

    public int getMovingIndex() {
        return movingIndex;
    }

    public void setMovingIndex(int movingIndex) {
        this.movingIndex = movingIndex;
    }

}
```

```
enum SpriteDirection {
    FORWARD, LEFT, AWAY, RIGHT
}
```

---

---

And an example using your code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Rotation2 extends JPanel {

    private static final int PREF_W = 750;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(400, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    private double theta = 0.0;
    private JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 360, 0);

    public Rotation2() {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) image.createGraphics();
        g2.setColor(Color.red);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        g2.dispose(); 

        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(90);
        slider.setMinorTickSpacing(10);
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);
        slider.setPaintLabels(true);
        slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                theta = Math.toRadians(slider.getValue());
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        });
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.add(slider);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        int x = PREF_W / 2;
        int y = PREF_H / 2;
        g2.rotate(theta, x, y);
        int imgX = (PREF_W - image.getWidth()) / 2;
        int imgY = (PREF_H - image.getHeight()) / 2;
        g2.drawImage(image, imgX, imgY, this);
        g2.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rotation2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Rotation2());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: I was afraid this would be the solution. I was hoping that I could continue to use my method of `JPanels`, but it seems as if this is the proper way to implement what I'm trying to do. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Also, you said that I had a different User ID at the beginning of your response. I don't recall ever changing my User ID. Are you sure you're recalling the correct user?

Comment: @elektrikpulse61: perhaps not. Please see edits using your code.

Comment: I see. That is very interesting. I appreciate the time you've taken to help me. I think between your first post and your edits to my MCVE, I'll be able to work out a solution. Thank you!